# React - interview exercise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got the following React exercise with 2 components in an interview that I did not manage to make it compile...
The question was the following:

**Update the Counter component to take onIncrement callbacks as props and ensure they update the counter's values independently. Each callback should take a single, integer value as a parameter which is the amount to increment the counter's existing value by.**

Comments in the code but the my problem is how to implement the "onIncrement" function.

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

// state data for 3 counters
const data = [
  { id: 1, value: 1 },
  { id: 2, value: 2 },
  { id: 3, value: 3 }
];

// Counter Component
class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="counter">
        <b>{value}</b>
        <div className="counter-controls">
          <button className="button is-danger is-small">-</button>
          //I call the function passed     
          <button className="button is-success is-small" onClick={()=>{onIncrement(this.props.value)}}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }
  
   onIncrement=(value)=>{
   //I tried several things here but I did not manage to make it work. I guess that I need also the id of the object...
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       
        {data.map(counter => ( 
          <Counter 
            key={counter.id} 
            value={counter.value} 
             //I pass the callback function to the component
            onIncrement={this.onIncrement} 

            />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


render(
  <App/>
, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

Comment: Where did you encounter a problem or a lack of knowledge on how to proceed? You did not specify your specific problem

Comment: So what's your question/problem?

Comment: Edited. How to implement the onIncrement function, sorry.

Comment: Here's a clue: your Counter component isn't expecting/using an onIncrement prop. You should use `const { value, onIncrement } = this.props;` within the render method.

Comment: True that I was missing,I just forget it thanks :), but my issue is regarding the implementation of the OnIncrement, there I am clueless, another clue there? :)

Comment: Honestly, without passing any information about which counter is going to be updated, how could you update it?
I mean, when you call `onIncrement()` from a `Counter` Component, if you don't pass somehow the information on which `Counter` you are incrementing, you can't expect to know "by magic" from the `App` Component.

BTW, the const `data` is actually in the state of the `App` Component? Because you create no state in the `App` Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know an answer has been accepted, but it doesn't actually satisfy the requirements fully, i.e.

> Each callback should take a single, integer value as a parameter which is the amount to increment the counter's existing value by.

The accepted answer takes the event object as a parameter which is not the specified requirement. The only way to strictly satisfy the expected requirement is to bind unique

> "...onIncrement callbacks as props..."

for each counter. This approach has drawbacks and performance implications [as discussed in this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

**Working example at** https://codesandbox.io/s/j2vxj620z9

Comment: Yeah, agree with you. I was trying the solution today and thinking about the same! :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you'll want to use the `id` as a way to determine which `value` you need to update. How you have it set up, you won't be able to know which `value` needs to be updated (because you don't know which `id` was clicked) nor will the `value` be saved.

**NOTE**: The example below takes the `id` from `event.target.id` and the `value` from `event.target.value` which is then deconstructed in the `handleChange` callback. This is a more common and elegant solution than passing a value to a `callback` and then passing it and another value to another `callback` (more work, more code, but same functionality).

---

**Best solution**: https://codesandbox.io/s/rjmx8vw99p

**components/UpdateQuantity.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { id: "Apples", quantity: 0 },
      { id: "Strawberries", quantity: 0 },
      { id: "Grapes", quantity: 0 },
      { id: "Apricots", quantity: 0 }
    ]
  };

  handleChange = ({ target: { id, value } }) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: prevState.items.map(item => {
        const nextVal = item.quantity + ~~value; // ~~ === parseInt(val, 10) -- required because the "value" is turned into a string when placed on a DOM element

        return id === item.id
          ? { id, quantity: nextVal > 0 ? nextVal : 0 }
          : { ...item };
      })
    }));
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Updating Values Inside Array</h1>
      {this.state.items.map(({ id, quantity }) => (
        <div key={id} className="container">
          <div>
            {id} ({quantity})
          </div>
          <button
            id={id}
            value={1}
            style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
            className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
            onClick={this.handleChange}
          >
            +
          </button>
          <button
            id={id}
            value={-1}
            style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
            className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
            onClick={this.handleChange}
          >
            -
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

**Another solution**: https://codesandbox.io/s/yq961275rv (not recommended as it requires an extra component and an extra callback -- BUT there's no binding required in the `render` method nor is there an anonymous function `() => {}` in the `onClick` callback)

**components/UpdateQuantity.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Button from "./button";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { id: "Apples", quantity: 0 },
      { id: "Strawberries", quantity: 0 },
      { id: "Grapes", quantity: 0 },
      { id: "Apricots", quantity: 0 }
    ]
  };

  handleChange = (id, val) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: prevState.items.map(item => {
        const nextVal = item.quantity + val;

        return id === item.id
          ? { id, quantity: nextVal > 0 ? nextVal : 0 }
          : { ...item };
      })
    }));
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Updating Values Inside Array</h1>
      {this.state.items.map(props => (
        <div key={props.id} className="container">
          <div>
            {props.id} ({props.quantity})
          </div>
          <Button
            {...props}
            className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            value={1}
          >
            +
          </Button>
          <Button
            {...props}
            disabled={props.quantity === 0}
            className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            value={-1}
          >
            -
          </Button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**components/button.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class Button extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    className: PropTypes.string,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.handleChange(this.props.id, this.props.value);
  };

  render = () => (
    <button
      disabled={this.props.disabled || false}
      className={this.props.className}
      onClick={this.handleClick}
      style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Updated answer and explanation. Also, I included an alternative solution to the accepted answer, which avoids binding in the render method.