# I can't sum every instance of a property in State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After resolving [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915882/state-changes-but-not-reflected-in-dom). At the last phase of the project, I am now having an issue with summing the votes for each of the political parties. Someone suggested to me to use Redux, I learnt  [it and started using the state management system](https://github.com/CodingIsFood/e-electionAppRedux), but unfortunately, I got stuck at the point of adding new state values. I suspect  it was from my action that was meant to update the array.

The issue I was originally having is on how to add state values per political party. I want to know the sum of all APC and PDP votes individually. I have tried different techniques but none was successful, this is the last clean [https://github.com/CodingIsFood/e-election-collation-app state of the code].

Please I look forward to stackoverflowers assisting me to resolve the issue (either the redux version or the non-redux version).

Basically, what I need an algorithm for is that let's say we have a property x, which is in a component A, the value of x changes based on the inputs provided by another component B. There is a parent child relationship between A and B. I want to sum every instance of x, every-time it changes.

Comment: Sorry it is a bit unclear on which data you are trying to sum up APC and PDP votes, is this structure of it? 
https://github.com/CodingIsFood/e-election-collation-app/blob/master/src/components/Datasource.jsx

Comment: I will like to sum both, because I will still add a conditional statement that will determine the winner of the election. Yes. Its for it, but there is also provision for adding more content to the datasource through forms, but still using the same structure. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes but that file is data structure on which you are doing summation?

Comment: Yes. that is the file, but data can be added to it during runtime. The file was used to initialize the state.

Comment: That is fine, just structure is important. Would be good to add it in question. 
Answer is added bellow. Reduce is invoked on Datasource, but you can execute it on whichever array you keep your data in

Answer (score 1):

based on structure of your datasource file, following function executed on your data should work

```
Datasource.reduce((sum, a) => {
    if(!sum.apcVotes) sum.apcVotes = 0;
    if(!sum.pdpVotes) sum.pdpVotes = 0;
    sum.pdpVotes += parseInt(a.pdpVotes)
    sum.apcVotes += parseInt(a.apcVotes)
    return sum;
}, {})
```

Result will be in following structure:

```
{apcVotes: 250, pdpVotes: 301}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am pretty sure this algorithm is the solution I need, but when I try to console log (both through the function or in the render function) it always returns "undefined", no error, just undefined. What do you think can be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean through function or in render. What exactly are you logging where

Comment: I mean putting your suggested solution in a function, like functionName, then doing a {console.log(this.functionName)}. It should ordinarily return the two values in the object sum, but it is saying undefined.

Comment: You have to show me actual code. console.log(this.functionName)  doesn't return anything as you are not invoking that function here

Comment: I have updated the repository based on my comment. Thanks for the help. https://github.com/CodingIsFood/e-election-collation-app

Comment: There is nothing in repository that uses code above, last commit is shown was yesterday

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189447/discussion-between-cynthia-blessing-and-chriss).